# Apache FOP XSL/XSLT - Making text bold in generated PDF

Tags: xml, apache, xslt, apache-fop

I have an xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TermsAndConditions>
        <clause><clausetext>Terms and Conditions of Supply - Please read carefully</clausetext></clause>
        <clause><clausetext>Available only to <bold>customers who have an existing</bold> account.</clausetext></clause>
</TermsAndConditions>
```

and the style sheet is:

```
<fo:page-sequence master-reference="simple" >
        <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">       
        <xsl:for-each select="data/TermsAndConditions/clause">
                <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="Arial" color="#6d6e71"><xsl:value-of select="clausetext" />
</fo:block>
                <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="Arial" line-height="10pt" space-after.optimum="3pt" text-align="justify">&#0160;</fo:block>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </fo:flow>
</fo:page-sequence>
```

How do I go about making the text between the tags < bold > < /bold > as bold in the generated pdf? At the moment, I can see the clauses, but the text is all normal.

Further to this, I tried a similar thing using w3schools.com's tryit editor:
[ http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=cdcatalog&xsltfile=tryxsl_if ]

with the following style sheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
     <xsl:apply-templates mode="tttt" />
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="bold" mode="tttt">
     <b><xsl:value-of select="." /></b>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and I get the output as desired.

Comment: The stylesheet you show produces hrml. You need to at least be working with XSL FO for Apache FOP

Comment: I am working with xsl fo. The second style sheet was based on the first one just as a proof of concept.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`<b>` is html syntax, for fo this probably should read:

```
<xsl:template match="bold" mode="tttt">
     <fo:inline font-weight="bold"><xsl:value-of select="." /></fo:inline>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: @user2260040, you did not accept a lot of answers, which is the way of saying "Thanks" on SO - did this answer help you, or what could we do to help you?